# Inserting text into HTML from AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-ng-model

In my `index.html` file, I have created a very bare-bones form. I have separated much of the detail into `app.js` so that if someone wants to have their version of the form look different, they just have to insert a modified copy of `app.js` (trying to go for portability here).

However, I am very new to AngularJS, which is what a lot of `app.js` is using. I could use some help please!

Here is a code snippet that I'm having some trouble with:

```
<body ng-controller="controller">
<div class="page">
  <section class="signin">
  <form name="form" novalidate>

    <div class="intro">
      <label ng-model="service-desk-name"></label>
      <span ng-bind="service-desk-name"></span>
      <label ng-model="welcome"></label>
      <span ng-bind="welcome"></span>
    </div>
```

Coupled with:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.service-desk-name = 'Arbitrary Service Desk Name';
    $scope.welcome = 
        'Please sign in and a consultant will be with you shortly.';
}]);
```

Because I may be doing something dreadfully wrong, I'll explain what I want to do. The `intro` section is displayed above the actual form, showing the service desk name, and some kind of custom welcome or informational message through `ng-model="service-desk-name"` and `ng-model="welcome"`, respectively. My hope is that I can get the HTML to grab value of these two models that I define in `app.js`. This way, the HTML doesn't control what is displayed, it just grabs what is defined and displays it.

Right now, these fields are not showing up at all on the webpage, indicating that there's just some kind of syntax error. I'm so new to Angular so I don't really know what to try to fix it from here.

Answer (score 3):

replace

```
<label ng-model="service-desk-name"></label>
```

with

```
<label>{{service-desk-name}}</label>
```

`ng-model` means that you want bi-directional binding, and is used for example with `input`s, so that when you start typing into the `input`, the value is stored inside anything that you reference through `ng-model`, i.e.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="inputValue" />
```

will save the input into `$scope.inputValue`

`{{}}` means you want to output something from the controller in the view.

Comment: Makes sense now that you've clarified that difference for me. That worked! I just had to change the `service-desk-name` variable to `servicedeskkiosk` to fix a syntax error.

Comment: true, didn't notice that!

Answer (score 1):

Variable name can not have most special character (except `_`, `$`) when you are defining directly after a `.`(dot). This is the reason where controller code is throwing an error, since nothing is getting rendered on page.

You could define that property by specifying key over `$scope` object like

```
$scope['service-desk-name'] = 'Arbitrary Service Desk Name';
```

Additionally the `ng-model` would work on `input` element only, but you are using over `label`. Do below change to `welcome` as well.

```
<input ng-model="service-desk-name"/>
```

> But Ideally you shouldn't be define scope variable in such format.
>   Preferred way would be to use `camelCase` while defining variables.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Pankaj Parkar

Also you can't get value in this case because you don't set "ng-app"

[plnkr link](https://plnkr.co/edit/EZv0S5bEhttTxDTfyth9)

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);


app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.serviceDeskName = 'Arbitrary Service Desk Name';
    $scope.welcome = 'Please sign in and a consultant will be with you shortly.';
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app"> <!-- For example define your app module name here -->

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myController">
  <div class="page">
    <section class="signin">
      <form name="form" novalidate>
        <div class="intro">
          <label ng-model="serviceDeskName"></label>
          <span ng-bind="serviceDeskName"></span>
          <hr>
          <label ng-model="welcome"></label>
          <span ng-bind="welcome"></span>
        </div>
      </form>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I do set it. I just didn't show it because it was a small code snippet.

Comment: Sorry, if so. Then just variable naming :)
I've made some additional changes like an app.controller('myController', function ($scope) { });

myController - change name to not confuse in future
and you have wrapper function in [ ]; I've removed them